# how to fix "file.cmpr: unknown suffix -- ignored"

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script that takes a .cmpr compressed file and uncompress it.

I've tried running the following command in the shell to see if it works -

```
uncompress file.cmpr
```

but the file is not being uncompressed and I get the following message -

```
gzip: file.cmpr: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

I want to use the 'uncompress' command as specified in here - 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uncompress.1p.html

how do I fix this? how to I add support for '.cmpr' files on my machine? or is it something else

Comment: Rename your file from `file.cmpr` to `file.cmpr.gz` and use `gunzip`. See: `man gunzip`.

Comment: thanks this is working, but I still want to use the uncompress command. maybe more information may be helpful - when I type in the shell - ````file file.cmpr```` I get that the file type is ````file.cmpr: compress'd data 16 bits```` which means that I should be able to uncompress the file. isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uncompress` expects files to have a `.Z` suffix. Rename it to `file.Z` and then run either `uncompress file.Z` or `uncompress file`—either one works.

Comment: by any chance you know where the .cmpr suffix comes from? I do not seem to find any information about it online, and (using GUI in linux) I don't see that compressing a file to .cmpr archive is supported